# Keep referenced field data changes

Tags: database

I have a table `Salary` with a column `PersonalId` and a table `Person` with a column `Name`.

In the first table salary data will saved with a `PersonalId` which relates it to the `Person` table. In salary bill all data will gather together and `Person` name will be referenced from `Person` table.

After 1 year a specific person name will change from `Michael` to `Maic`. Now I want the last year salaries bill remain with previous person name `Michael` and the new salaries bill generate by new name `Maic`.

How we can do that?

Comment: Is there any datetime field ?

Answer (score 0):

It could depend on what type of operation you need to to most and on how much people change their name, because the number of joins you may need to make could vary a lot.

- keep a field in Person that points to the next Person which is a change of name
- keep another key in Person that varies only for the physical person
- keep a limited number of names in Person that someone could dispose of, with an index of the current name
- in another table you keep the relations between the various name of the Person

It could depend on what rules of normalization you follow, for now I'm not thinking about that.
Anyway, with the first case you don't need to change `Salary`, but to reconstruct the identity of a `Person` you need multiple requests or at least a stored procedure.
In the second case you still don't need to change `Salary` because you add a field to `Person`, but to get all the `Salary` entries for that physical person you'll need some work, again probably a stored procedure to get the added field and then something that joins all the `Salary` entries.
The third maybe is the simplest, but also the limited one, and you need in `Salary` another field that tells the index of the name to use in that entry.
The last case gives you a stable identity, but it may need some work because of the added table, and still there are multiple implementations. You could have salary reference that table instead of `Person`, or you could consult that table only when you need all the data, but you cannot reference its primary key from `Salary` because it would not permit to discriminate the name.

Comment: @Thomas W the problem is with normalization: with your solution there's duplicated data with no constraint, that's why I wrote "it depends on the rules of normalizations you follow"

Answer (score 0):

Lunadir's right in a certain way -- but all of those approaches are complex, and of rather great difficulty.

The other way -- simpler, and perhaps more correct & robust -- is to keep NAME and PAID_DATE columns in Salary or SalaryPaid, and write the actual name & date paid at the time the payment is made.

Good old batch-processing style -- and it has the benefit of actually capturing the key financial facts, of what payment was made & what name it was made to, which are the actual auditable transaction history.

Do you pay each Salary entry individually, or in bunch (PaySlip or SalaryPaid)?  Put the NAME column wherever you record the actual payment & timestamp it occurred.